# Dynamically initializing and working with an array of C++ STL list

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class in which I have declared the array of list as a data member.

```
list <int> **listOfNodes;
```

I have allocated space for the pointers to lists in the constructor of the class as follows (here 'v' is the no. of lists I want, passed to the constructor as an argument.)

```
listOfNodes=new list<int>* [v];
for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
{
    list<int> temp;
    listOfNodes[i]=&temp;  //declaring a new list and making the list pointer point to it
}
```

Now I have the following code inside the function for taking the input from the user and adding it to the corresponding list. For example, if user enters 2 5, I need to push_back a new entry 5 into the list with index 2, i.e, the list pointed to by listOfNodes[2].

```
int u,v;
cin>>u>>v;
(*(listOfNodes[u])).push_back(v);
```

But, somehow my code crashes on execution.
Can someone please point out what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: What is wrong is that you are using a pointer of pointers to `std::list<int>`. I suggest using `std::vector`(s) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
{
    list<int> temp;
    listOfNodes[i]=&temp;  
} // <- each temp is destructed here.
```

your `temp` lists are automatically allocated. That means **once you go out of the loop scope they are destructed**. Now your `listOfNodes[i]` is pointing to some destructed memory (*probably they are pointing to the same location because the compiler keeps allocating temp at the same address each time. Still invalid though.*).

You should instead do it like

```
for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
{
    listOfNodes[i] = new list<int>;  
}
```

---

And don't forget to `delete` the dynmaically allocated memory. You should probably just use a **list/vector of lists** or use a list of [**smart pointers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Named. I was struggling with this for few hours. And yes, I also thought of using a vector of lists later but wanted to figure out what was wrong with this code. Would also read about smart pointers. Thanks again for such a quick reply and added advices. :) My first question on SO and I am highly impressed (in addition to the respect I have for SO's already asked quest. for helping me out billions of times). Would definitely have upvoted had I had some reputation.

Comment: @Shobhit :) No problem man. I am glad it helped. And don't worry about the upvote. I have got two already. It is enough :)

Comment: Who keeps downvoting my answers? I really don't get it. Could you please mention why?

Comment: @Named: If you are regularly downvoted without commentary on posts without obvious problems (as this one, +1) and you think there is a pattern, you can contact SO officials and ask them to check if there are voting irregularities. But do so only if it exceeds an acceptable level.

Comment: @bitmask Thank you. I think I should. The reason I am suspecting it because there is no comment left with the down-vote. I will wait and see if it passes, otherwise I will contact them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid mixing C++ containers (list,vector,set,...) with C containers (plain array). If you want to keep a number of lists use vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::list<int>>> nodes;
```

instead of

```
std::list<int>** listOfNodes;
```

It is very cumbersome to keep track of the list instances by hand (exactly what you experienced). So let the vector (or whatever else you deem fit, an `std::array` might easily be more appropriate depending on your situation) take care of handling the list instances.

Comment: Thank you @bitmask for the useful suggestion. Yes, I later did think of using a vector of lists as suggested by you, but wanted to figure out the loophole in my initial code. And once again, Would have definitely upvoted had I had some reputation.

Comment: @rubenvb: I know it's a weird formulation, but I wanted to point out that arrays are what you (have to) use in C if you want a vector-style container. In that regard, `int[]` is not an idiomatic C++ container (but the metaphor shouldn't be stretched too much, I agree).